# Google App Engine Python Authentication from API

Tags: python, api, google-app-engine, web-applications

I'm currently building a Python webapp on the Google App Engine and I want to expose various parts of my application via a JSON API. This API may be used in the form of a mobile client, or (for the purposes of testing) a headless Python script.

I need to be able to authenticate users before they perform operations on the API. I notice that the Users API does not support simple authentication [in the form of authenticate(username, password)] so merely sending the username/password to a URL and then later using some given token would not work.

Ultimately, I would like the application to use Facebook Connect in addition to its own logins.

Could somebody please suggest how is the best way to authenticate users in this situation, using a remote JSON API and the Google App Engine?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the record, I ended up going with the wonderful [Tipfy](http://www.tipfy.org) framework in the end.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the recently released [oauth support](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/oauth/). Failing that, you can implement your own authentication, for example by using simple or digest authentication.